Children's sci-fi book about a boy who finds an alien woman with a special stone that shows him her world while she regenerates
So there was a children's book I picked up from Dodworth Library in Barnsley, South Yorkshire, UK, somewhere in the years 2002-2007. The book definitely won't be newer than 2008 and I doubt would be any older than 1990/1995.
I have no idea of its name or the author's name but I remember that the main character was a boy I think aged around 8-12 years old and he somehow came across this woman who looked human (I think) but was from another planet and she was injured/dying. She has with her a stone that used to communicate with her home world or something like that and she teaches the boy how to hold it so it doesn't just slip out of his hand like slime. With this stone, he's able to see things from her world. Meanwhile, she succumbs to whatever injuries she has and he hides her under his bed while she goes through some kind of healing process. At first, the woman starts to smell like she's decomposing, so the boy's mum keeps saying about needing to clean his room but he makes sure she stays clear.
He sometimes takes this stone to school with him but is mainly always rushing home to see how the woman's doing. I think it takes maybe three days or something for her to heal, during which time the boy spends his time laid on his bed with the stone in his hand learning about her world. To anyone else, and his increasingly concerned mum, it just looks like he's staring at the ceiling.
I doubt the book is US-based, as it was read in the UK, but I can't rule it out. I'm also sure the woman had a weird name.

Could the book have been set in Australia? Something about this sounds familiar.

Possibly https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/924963.Beyond_the_Labyrinth ?

I don't think it's this one. This seems more for teenagers and it was definitely a more gentle, childhood vibe it had going on. Thanks for trying though.
